# Calculate F-distribution p values in python?

Tags: python, math, statistics, probability

Suppose that I have an F value and the associated degrees of freedom, df1 and df2.  How can I use python to programmatically calculate the p value associated with these numbers?

Note:  I would not accept a solution using scipy or statsmodels.

Comment: You don't want scipy, how about numpy and statsmodels?  Maybe show us what you've tried.

Comment: Are you sure numpy has this ability?  I've already searched their docs but the stats ability of numpy is very limited.  Using statsmodels is not possible; I'll edit the question in light of that.

Comment: It's been said many times, but SO isn't a code writing service, though many people are willing to help out even with that. But when you explicitly eliminate the packages that should be used for this, the least you can do is show us what you tried.

Comment: Jeff, it's not like there's a formula for this that I can just write code for.  This task should essentially be a one-liner via some package or other (excluding the above mentioned) - I just don't know which one.  I've searched for solutions elsewhere, but they all use scipy.  I've also read the numpy docs and dir'd the package, but there is no mention of this feature.

Comment: If you already have the test statistic and degrees of freedom, then you can just use `scipy.stats.f.sf`. You can look at the source code of scipy.stats or statsmodels for examples. scipy.stats.f.sf is a wrapper around the corresponding function in scipy.special

Comment: Sorry user333700, but I'm looking for a solution that avoids scipy.

Comment: A few years ago there were distributions implemented with just python floating around, but I don't find them anymore with a Google search. And I would never do anything without scipy, so I didn't keep track of any bookmarks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CDF for the F-distribution (and hence the p-value) can be calculated with the regularized (incomplete) beta function `I(x; a, b)`, see, e.g., [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/F-Distribution.html).  Using the code for `I(x; a, b)` from this [blog](https://malishoaib.wordpress.com/2014/04/15/the-beautiful-beta-functions-in-raw-python/), which uses only `math`, the p-value is

```
1 - incompbeta(.5*df1, .5*df2, float(df1)*F/(df1*F+df2))
```

Here the result for some sample values, matching `scipy.stats.f.sf`:

```
In [57]: F, df1, df2 = 5, 20, 18

In [58]: 1 - incompbeta(.5*df1, .5*df2, float(df1)*F/(df1*F+df2))
Out[58]: 0.0005812207389501722

In [59]: st.f.sf(F, df1, df2)
Out[59]: 0.00058122073922042188
```

Just in case the blog disappears, here the code:

```
import math

def incompbeta(a, b, x):

    ''' incompbeta(a,b,x) evaluates incomplete beta function, here a, b > 0 and 0 <= x <= 1. This function requires contfractbeta(a,b,x, ITMAX = 200) 
    (Code translated from: Numerical Recipes in C.)'''

    if (x == 0):
        return 0;
    elif (x == 1):
        return 1;
    else:
        lbeta = math.lgamma(a+b) - math.lgamma(a) - math.lgamma(b) + a * math.log(x) + b * math.log(1-x)
        if (x < (a+1) / (a+b+2)):
            return math.exp(lbeta) * contfractbeta(a, b, x) / a;
        else:
            return 1 - math.exp(lbeta) * contfractbeta(b, a, 1-x) / b;

def contfractbeta(a,b,x, ITMAX = 200):

    """ contfractbeta() evaluates the continued fraction form of the incomplete Beta function; incompbeta().  
    (Code translated from: Numerical Recipes in C.)"""

    EPS = 3.0e-7
    bm = az = am = 1.0
    qab = a+b
    qap = a+1.0
    qam = a-1.0
    bz = 1.0-qab*x/qap

    for i in range(ITMAX+1):
        em = float(i+1)
        tem = em + em
        d = em*(b-em)*x/((qam+tem)*(a+tem))
        ap = az + d*am
        bp = bz+d*bm
        d = -(a+em)*(qab+em)*x/((qap+tem)*(a+tem))
        app = ap+d*az
        bpp = bp+d*bz
        aold = az
        am = ap/bpp
        bm = bp/bpp
        az = app/bpp
        bz = 1.0
        if (abs(az-aold)<(EPS*abs(az))):
            return az

    print 'a or b too large or given ITMAX too small for computing incomplete beta function.'
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for!  Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome.  ALGLIB also has [`I(x; a, b)`](http://www.alglib.net/specialfunctions/incompletebeta.php), but while ALGLIB can be used from Python, it is not on PyPI.